# Property 'toDos' does not exist on type TS2339

Tags: typescript, react-hooks, reducers, react-tsx

I'm a beginner learning ts for the first time. Thank you in advance for sharing your knowledge.
I am making a todolist. I used react to complete it. But now I am using react and typescript together to complete the code.

It seems to me that 'reducer' is not working properly. How can I operate this? I'd appreciate it if you let me know. This is 'App.tsx' code with surface error.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Add from "./Add";
import List from "./List";
import ToDo from "./ToDo";
import Title from "./Title";
import Progress from "./Progress";
import styled from "styled-components";

interface ITodo {
  toDos: string;
  completed: boolean;
}

function App() {
  const { toDos, completed } = useState<ITodo>();  Error part
  return (
    <Title>
      <Add />
      <Progress />
      <Lists>
        <List title={toDos.length !== 0 ? "To Dos" : ""}>
          {toDos.map((toDo: any) => (
            <ToDo key={toDo.id} id={toDo.id} text={toDo.text} isCompleted={false} />
          ))}
        </List>
        <List title={completed.length !== 0 ? "Completed" : ""}>
          {completed.map((toDo: any) => (
            <ToDo key={toDo.id} id={toDo.id} text
              {...toDo.text} isCompleted />
          ))}
        </List>
      </Lists>
    </Title>
  );
}

export default App;
```

This code is the 'reducer.tsx' code that I thought there was a problem.

```
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from "uuid";
import { ADD, DEL, COMPLETE, UNCOMPLETE, EDIT } from "./actions";

export const initialState = {
  toDos: [],
  completed: [],
};

const reducer = ({ state, action }: any) => {
  switch (action) {
    case ADD:
      return {
        ...state,
        toDos: [...state.toDos, { text: action.payload, id: uuidv4() }],
      };
    case DEL:
      return {
        ...state,
        toDos: state.toDos.filter((toDo: { id: number; }) => toDo.id !== action.payload),
      };
    case COMPLETE:
      const target = state.toDos.find((toDo: { id: number; }) => toDo.id === action.payload);
      return {
        ...state,
        toDos: state.toDos.filter((toDo: { id: number; }) => toDo.id !== action.payload),
        completed: [...state.completed, { ...target }],
      };
    case UNCOMPLETE:
      const aTarget = state.completed.find(
        (toDo: { id: any; }) => toDo.id === action.payload
      );
      return {
        ...state,
        toDos: [...state.toDos, { ...aTarget }],
        completed: state.completed.filter(
          (complete: { id: number; }) => complete.id !== action.payload
        ),
      };
    case EDIT:
      const bTarget = state.toDos.find((toDo: { id: number; }) => toDo.id === action.id);
      const rest = state.toDos.filter((toDo: { id: number; }) => toDo.id !== action.id);
      return {
        ...state,
        toDos: rest.concat({ ...bTarget, text: action.payload }),
      };
    default:
      return;
  }
};

export default reducer;
```

This code is 'context.tsx' code.

```
import React, { createContext, useReducer, useContext } from 'react';
import reducer, { initialState } from "./reducer";

export type Todo = {
  id: number;
  text: string;
  done: boolean;
};

export type TodosState = Todo[];

const ToDosContext = createContext<TodosState | any>(undefined);

const ToDosProvider = ({ children }: { children: React.ReactNode }) => {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialState);
  return (
    <ToDosContext.Provider value={{ state, dispatch }}>
      {children}
    </ToDosContext.Provider>
  );
};

export const useDispatch = () => {
  const { dispatch } = useContext(ToDosContext);
  return dispatch;
};

export const useState = () => {
  const { state } = useContext(ToDosContext);
  return state;
};

export default ToDosProvider;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's happening here is due to confusing naming.  You created a custom hook `useState` which shares its name with a built-in React hook and you’re using the wrong one.

You get an error here:

```
const { toDos, completed } = useState<ITodo>();  Error part
```

Because of this:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
```

You wanted to be using your custom `useState` hook, which returns an object with properties `toDos` and `completed`.  But instead of importing that hook, you imported the built-in React hook `useState` which returns an array with two entries (`state` and `setState`).

Go into `context.tsx` and rename your custom hooks to something less ambiguous, like `useTodosState` and `useTodosDispatch`.  This isn't strictly required but it will make life so much easier!

Then go into `App.tsx` and replace `useState` with `useTodosState`, making sure to import it from `context.tsx`.  Now that there's no doubt about which hook you intended to use, you won't need to worry about your IDE auto-importing `useState` from React.

Comment: I solved this problem thanks to you. But another issue appeared. Can you tell me this? Thank you for your hard work. 
TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'toDos' of 'Object(...)(...)' as it is undefined.
`const { toDos, completed } = useTodosState();` 
This is still the problem.

Comment: It sounds like you might not be inside a ToDosProvider.  Make sure that you wrap your entire App component in a ToDosProvider.